# .NET: How to access ExceptionContext object from Exception object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm writing a custom error-handling method, and am passing it an Exception object. I need to be able to access that Exception's ExceptionContext object, so I can set a property to true before I execute the Error view. Does anyone know how to get to the ExceptionContext, given just an Exception object?

For reference, the reason I need the ExceptionContext object is so I can perform the code below:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true; // filterContext is of type ExceptionContext
this.View("Error_partial", filterContext.Exception).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
```

I've read online that ExceptionHandled *must* be set to true, or the following statement will throw a yellow screen of death, rather than the friendly "Error_partial" page I'd like it to. So it's important that I be able to access the ExceptionContext of the Exception. Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, and I presume you've solved this already, but for the benefit of others:

You can create a class that implements `IExceptionFilter`, and add that to the filters collection for your controller, or to the `GlobalFilterCollection`.  Put your custom exception-handling logic into the class's `OnException` method, which accepts an `ExceptionContext` argument.  That's the object whose `ExceptionHandled` property must be set to `true` to avoid the yellow screen of death.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have an existing `ExceptionContext` object already;

You should create one and pass your `Exception` object to it, then it will create an `ExceptionContext` based on the `Exception` object you passed it.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492691(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @Tony, I guess I did think about doing this, but I wondered if the ExceptionContext's associated properties would still be the same. Obviously if I create a new one, wouldn't the properties be reset? Maybe it doesn't matter, given what I'm trying to do...

Comment: @Mega Matt, from what I understand in the MSDN library, it says it will use the current Exception object to create a new object, so if it needs to set any properties I guess it would do so.  I am not sure however...